# Creating randomized ID that applies for two separate scripts

Tags: jquery, contact-form

I'm not sure how to solve this, so hopefully, some of you have a great solution.

I've set up two contact forms - one for the initial information and a second form with relevant follow-up questions. Please note that it is on purpose that it sends two different forms.

When receiving the information by email, I would like a random ID, e.g.: #42432, to indicate that both emails received come from the same session/person.

```
<!-- Part 1 --> 
<script>
function send1() {
    var form_name = jQuery('[name=name]').val();
    var form_title = jQuery('[name=title]').val();
    var form_email = jQuery('[name=email]').val();
    var form_textarea = jQuery('[name=textarea]').val();

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("contact-form").innerHTML =
                this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "php/contact1.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("name="+form_name+"&title="+form_title+"&email="+form_email+"&textarea="+form_textarea);
}
</script>
<!-- Part 2 -->
<script>
    function send2() {
        var form_industry = jQuery("[name='industry']").is(":checked");
        var form_academia = jQuery("[name=academia]").is(":checked");
        var form_targeted = jQuery("[name=targeted]").is(":checked");
        var form_discovery = jQuery("[name=discovery]").is(":checked");
        var form_dunno = jQuery("[name=dunno]").is(":checked");
        var form_samples = jQuery('[name=samples]').val();
        var form_groups = jQuery('[name=groups]').val();
        var form_groups2 = jQuery('[name=groups2]').val();
        var form_biological = jQuery('[name=biological]').val();
        var form_technical = jQuery('[name=technical]').val();
        var form_source = jQuery('[name=source]').val();
        var form_origen = jQuery('[name=origen]').val();
        var form_extraction = jQuery('[name=extraction]').val();
        var form_aim = jQuery('[name=aim]').val();
        var form_phone = jQuery('[name=phone]').val();      
        var form_affiliated = jQuery('[name=affiliated]').val();
        var form_textarea = jQuery('[name=textarea]').val();

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("contact-form").innerHTML =
                    this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "php/contact2.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        xhttp.send("industry="+form_industry+"&academia="+form_academia+"&targeted="+form_targeted+"&discovery="+form_discovery+"&dunno="+form_dunno+"&samples="+form_samples+"&groups="+form_groups+"&groups2="+form_groups2+"&biological="+form_biological+"&technical="+form_technical+"&source="+form_source+"&origen="+form_origen+"&extraction="+form_extraction+"&aim="+form_aim+"&phone="+form_phone+"&affiliated="+form_affiliated+"&textarea="+form_textarea);
    }
</script>
```

Example of xhttp.open("POST", "php/contact1.php":

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

$email_from = 'New contact';
$email_subject = 'New Contact - Request with Questionary';
$email_body = "New contact request (Request with Questionary):
\n".
            "Name: $name\n".
            "Title: $title\n".
            "Email: $email\n".
            "Message: $textarea\n";


$to = "email@email.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers = "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header("location: https://website.com/php/questionary.html");
?>
```

The PHP file for the second form is built in the same way.

I'm looking forward to hearing your solutions.

All the best,

Louis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate GUID or random number like mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid) as Global Variable that will be available in both forms if forms are loaded in same page without reloading. For example :

```
<script>
function uuidv4() {
    const a = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint16Array(8));
    let i = 0;
    return '00-0-4-1-000'.replace(/[^-]/g, 
            s => (a[i++] + s * 0x10000 >> s).toString(16).padStart(4, '0')
    );
}

var guidVariable = uuidv4();

function send1() {
    ...
    xhttp.open("POST", "php/contact1.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("name="+form_name+"&title="+form_title+"&email="+form_email+"&textarea="+form_textarea+"&guidVariable ="+guidVariable );
}
</script>


<!-- Part 2 -->
<script>
    function send2() {
        ...    
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("contact-form").innerHTML =
                    this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "php/contact2.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        xhttp.send("industry="+form_industry+"&academia="+form_academia+"&targeted="+form_targeted+"&discovery="+form_discovery+"&dunno="+form_dunno+"&samples="+form_samples+"&groups="+form_groups+"&groups2="+form_groups2+"&biological="+form_biological+"&technical="+form_technical+"&source="+form_source+"&origen="+form_origen+"&extraction="+form_extraction+"&aim="+form_aim+"&phone="+form_phone+"&affiliated="+form_affiliated+"&textarea="+form_textarea+"&guidVariable ="+guidVariable );
    }
</script>
```

Reference [How to create a GUID / UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid)

Comment: Pranav, it worked like a charm. Thanks you very much.